# Parse XML child nodes with Scrapy

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrap an XML file. Scrapy gives you the option to scrap through any node name such as `<listing>`:

```
<listing>
 <img>1.jpg</img>
</listing>
<listing>
 <img>1.jpg</img>
 <img>2.jpg</img>
</listing>
<listing>
 <img>1.jpg</img>
 <img>2.jpg</img>
</listing>
```

Here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
class spider(XMLFeedSpider):
 name='spider'
 start_urls=['http://www.expample.com/xml.xml']
 itertag='listing'
 def parse_node(self,response,node):
  self.logger.info('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s', self.itertag, ''.join(node.extract()))
```

I can define the node with 'itertag' setting which is currently at 'listing'. I would like to run through every `<listing>` and then run through every `<img>` for each `<listing>`. How can I parse subnodes (child nodes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a list of `scrapy.Item` or `scrapy.http.Request` objects to be returned in `parse_node`.

```
  sources = [Item(src=src) in for src in node.xpath('//img/text()').extract()]
  return sources
```

#### References:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.XMLFeedSpider.parse_node